# run excel formula only if date is in a specific range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that works for an entire column.

I would like to run this same formula but ONLY if column C is between today and 7 days before today.

This is my formula :

=(ROUND(COUNTIF(graFabrication!O:O,"0")/COUNTIF(graFabrication!O:O,">-1")*100,1)&"%")

I just can't figure it out

Comment: Wrap your formulae in an if() with the logical test on the dates. Or replace the countif() with countifs() but with your structure of countif() twice that is more work.

Comment: @SolarMike I just can't figure how to write it, I know I need to wrap  it in an if statement, but i just can't figure how to write the logical test on the dates

Comment: IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false). You can test dates, as long as they are formatted correctly like date_A <= Date_B as Excel uses serial numbers for representing dates.

Comment: I  understand how 'if' works and how to write it, but with my formula, how would it work? my original formula counts the number of 0 and divide it by the total of values present in the list. The If statement should only count the number of 0 that are present between today and 7 days before today, and divide it by the total values present between today and 7 days before today. How would your proposition work?

Comment: IF(date_test,(ROUND(COUNTIF(graFabrication!O:O,"0")/COUNTIF(graFabrication!O:O,">-1")*100,1)&"%"),"") All you need now is to build your data_test.

Comment: IF(C:C>= now(ROUND(COUNTIF(graFabrication!O:O,"0")/COUNTIF(graFabrication!O:O,">-1")*100,1)&"%"),""))

Comment: I just don't know how to write it , can you please tell me so i can try and understand for the next time?

Comment: So, look at the answer I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

So did this as you provide so little data to work with:

[image]

To save you typing, here is the formula I created as text so you can copy:

```
IF(($D$1-C3)>7,"too old","do_this")
```

Then, and this bit I cannot test:

```
IF(($D$1-C3)>7,"too old",(ROUND(COUNTIF(graFabrication!O:O,"0")/COUNTIF(graFabrication!O:O,">-1")*100,1)&"%")
```

Is your function added.

And if the 7 days is inclusive you will need greater than or equal to.