# Apply a formula if a criteria is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list with 2 columns, A and B.

In A, theres dates, and in B there's values (0 or 1).

How do I write a formula to count every '0' in B if on the same line (column A) the date is the 1st january 2022.

Example:

```
a, b 
2022-02-01, 0 
2022-01-01, 0 
2021-03-19, 1
```

Answer:

Counter should be at 1

Comment: The date bit has been done for you.

Comment: it wasn't good  @SolarMike I dont think you understand my formula. Your answer was "if the date is between now and minus 7 days, do the formula". That's not what I need. So If it finds said date, it will just run the formula on the entire column O:O. But I dont think you read what the formula does

Comment: @SolarMike I modified my question, maybe it will be more clear that way. What do you think?

Comment: Perhaps you need to check up and understand <, >, <=, >=, = and test what you can control.

Comment: You asked for a control for 7 days, which is what I gave you. But perhaps I was misled as you question could have been clearer, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/71732075/4961700

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,DATE(2022,1,1),B:B,0)
```

[image]